# How would you clean up URL from tracking query string variables?

Tags: java, regex, url, clean-urls, data-cleaning

I have some 1000s of URLs and the task is to count their occurrences and print top frequent. The problem occurs when single article has multiple URLs. Example below:

```
http://mashable.com/2013/06/05/whistle/?utm_campaign=Feed:+Mashable+(Mashable)&utm_cid=Mash-Product-RSS-Pheedo-All-Partial&utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed
http://mashable.com/2013/06/05/whistle/?utm_campaign=Feed:+Mashable+(Mashable)&utm_cid=Mash-Product-RSS-Pheedo-All-Partial&utm_medium=feed&utm_source=feedburner
http://mashable.com/2013/06/05/whistle/?utm_campaign=Mash-Product-RSS-Pheedo-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Product-RSS-Pheedo-All-Partial&utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=dlvr.it
```

All of these point to same article, however, the way they differ is by some third party tracking variables. I can eliminate following using RegExp, but there could be unlimited variants. Also, I cannot drop entire query string as it could contain genuine variable (i.e. `show.php?p=12`)

```
utm_campaign
utm_cid
utm_medium
utm_source
```

*Question:*
Is there a comprehensive list of these variables? Have you done this in past with a better approach?

Comment: ok but the http header of that article must be the same right , you can get it and then check it with the others

Answer (score 0):

Also useing RegExp

```
  [?&](.*?)=
```

in url every variable start with '?' or '&' and must be end with '='

Comment: yes I know that :). is there any comprehensive list of tracking cookie names?

Comment: see example above in the question. three examples of mashable